# scp to copy all the files without directories

Tags: linux, scp

i am trying to copy files from remote machine to local machine using scp

```
scp -r username@hostname:/directory .
```

I want only the file to be copied instead of directories 
ie)

```
directory
     |directory2
         | file1
         | file2
     file12
```

After copying all the files the structure should be of this

```
localdirectory
    |file1
    |file1
    |file12
```

Is this possible using scp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine find and scp, something like this:

find localdirectory | xargs scp {your parameters}

find - returns all files, xargs - will collect their full paths and gives them as argument for scp

Answer (score 1):

Sergius is right, you can use find and scp in conjunction to achieve this. However you need to run find on remote machine over ssh first and then scp it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
scp -r username@hostname:{/directory/directory2/file1,/directory/directory2/file2,/directory/file12} localdirectory
```

or just `scp` one by one